# Yii2 - Generate Pdf on the fly and attach to email

Tags: pdf, yii2, response, email-attachments, swiftmailer

This is how I can generate pdf page

```
public function actionPdf(){
    Yii::$app->response->format = 'pdf';
    $this->layout = '//print';
    return $this->render('myview', []);
}
```

And this is how I send emails

```
$send = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('mytemplate',[])
    ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
    ->setTo($email)
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->send();
```

How I can generate pdf as a file and attach it to my emails on the fly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mailer have method called `attachContent()`, where you can put pdf file.

PDF should be rendered with output destination set as string, and then pass it as param to `attachContent()`.

Sample:

```
Yii::$app->mail->compose()
   ->attachContent($pathToPdfFile, [
        'fileName'    => 'Name of your pdf',
        'contentType' => 'application/pdf'
   ])
   // to & subject & content of message
   ->send();
```

Comment: Good answer, would be even better with a code example.

Comment: @user3574492 here you go ;)

Comment: shouldn't it be attach() instead of attachContent() if it's path to file?

Comment: @tomekK is right. I suggest you change `attachContent` with `attach` in your example. `attachContent` is useful when the file is created on the fly and it will not work as expected when the first parameter is a file path. For a file that already exists and it is available at some path, `attach` is the proper option. See the documentation: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-mailing#file-attachment

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it

In my controller:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('pdf',['model' => $model])); //pdf is a name of view file responsible for this pdf document
$path = $mpdf->Output('', 'S'); 

Yii::$app->mail->compose()
->attachContent($path, ['fileName' => 'Invoice #'.$model->number.'.pdf',   'contentType' => 'application/pdf'])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I sent mails in `Yii2`

```
private function sendPdfAsEmail($mpdf)
    {
        $mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'F');
        $send = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom('admin@test.com')
        ->setTo('to@gmail.com')
        ->setSubject('Test Message')
        ->setTextBody('Plain text content. YII2 Application')
        ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content.</b>')
        ->attach(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/filename.pdf')
        ->send();
        if($send) {
            echo "Send";
        }
    }
```

1. Pass the `mpdf` instance to our custom function.
2. Use the `F` option in `mpdf` to save the output as a file.
3. use the `attach` option in Yii mailer and set the path of the saved file.